# subtraction from a dictionary of dictionaries in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I want to find the difference in the unique_users for the latest day(2023-09-06)  and previous day(2023-09-07) for a specific hour  2 and 13 separately for each key 'bsnl' and  'other' and for a specific `Exception`. I need to consider the `Exception` and `Hour` and `Date` to calculate the difference.

```
    DateTime    Date    Hour    Exception   IMSI_Operator
0   2023-09-06 02:00:00 2023-09-06 00:00:00 2   s2ap    {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 50007, 'unique_users': 38880}, 'Other': {'total_sessions': 50, 'unique_users': 32}}
1   2023-09-06 13:00:00 2023-09-06 00:00:00 13  s2ap    {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 60004, 'unique_users': 49816}, 'Other': {'total_sessions': 34, 'unique_users': 22}}
2   2023-09-07 13:00:00 2023-09-07 00:00:00 13  s2ap    {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 45224, 'unique_users': 37525}, 'Other': {'total_sessions': 32, 'unique_users': 27}}
3   2023-09-07 02:00:00 2023-09-07 00:00:00 2   s2ap    {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 47713, 'unique_users': 37284}, 'Other': {'total_sessions': 43, 'unique_users': 27}}
```

What I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'Date': ['2023-09-06 00:00:00', '2023-09-06 00:00:00', '2023-09-07 00:00:00', '2023-09-07 00:00:00'],
    'Hour': [2, 13, 13, 2],
    'Exception': ['s2ap', 's2ap', 's2ap', 's2ap'],
    'IMSI_Operator': [
        {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 50007, 'unique_users': 38880}, 'Other': {'total_sessions': 50, 'unique_users': 32}},
        {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 60004, 'unique_users': 49816}, 'Other': {'total_sessions': 34, 'unique_users': 22}},
        {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 45224, 'unique_users': 37525}, 'Other': {'total_sessions': 32, 'unique_users': 27}},
        {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 47713, 'unique_users': 37284}, 'Other': {'total_sessions': 43, 'unique_users': 27}}
    ]
}

result_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'Date' to datetime
result_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(result_df['Date'])

# Filter for the latest day
latest_day = result_df[result_df['Date'] == result_df['Date'].max()]

# Filter for the previous day
previous_day = result_df[result_df['Date'] == (result_df['Date'].max() - pd.DateOffset(days=1))]

result = {}
for key in latest_day['IMSI_Operator'].values[0].keys():

    latest_unique_users = latest_day['IMSI_Operator'].values[0][key]['unique_users']
    previous_unique_users = previous_day['IMSI_Operator'].values[0][key]['unique_users']

    result[key] = {
        'unique_users_diff': latest_unique_users - previous_unique_users,
    }

print(result)
```

But I would like to get the difference in the original dataframe itself. The previous date `2023-09-06` rows are not neeed in the final dataframe.
my current code is not considering the specific hour and specific exception for the calcualtion.

Expected output:

```
Hour    Exception   Date    IMSI_Operator   bsnl_unique_users_diff  Other_unique_users_diff
    2   s2ap    2023-09-07  {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 60004, 'unique_users': 49816}, 'Other': {'total_sessions': 34, 'unique_users': 22}} -1596   5
    13  s2ap    2023-09-07  {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 50007, 'unique_users': 38880}, 'Other': {'total_sessions': 50, 'unique_users': 32}} -12291  -5
```

Comment: can you provide table of desired output?

Comment: `result_df` isn't defined in the code that you provided, please provide the full code

Comment: @PandaKim Updated the post.

Comment: @renzo21 updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with help of [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to rework the dictionaries to columns:

```
date1 = pd.Timestamp('2023-09-07')
date2 = pd.Timestamp('2023-09-06')
hours = [2, 13]

tmp = (df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['IMSI_Operator']))
         .query('Hour in @hours')
         .set_index(['Date', 'Hour'])
      )
cols = list(tmp.filter(like='unique_users'))


out = (tmp.reset_index()[list(df)]
          .merge(tmp.loc[date1, cols].sub(tmp.loc[date2, cols])
                    .add_suffix('_diff').assign(Date=date1),
                 on=['Date', 'Hour'], how='right')
          .reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
   index       Date  Hour Exception                                      IMSI_Operator  bsnl.unique_users_diff  Other.unique_users_diff
0      0 2023-09-07     2      s2ap  {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 47713, 'unique_use...                   -1596                       -5
1      1 2023-09-07    13      s2ap  {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 45224, 'unique_use...                  -12291                        5
```

Comment: Could you please break down this part: 

`out = (tmp.reset_index()[cols]
          .merge(tmp.loc[date1, cols].sub(tmp.loc[date2, cols]).add_suffix('_diff').assign(Date=date1),
                 on=['Date', 'Hour'], how='right')
          .reset_index()
      )
`
I am getting KeyError: 'Date'

Comment: i think it is because of `tmp.reset_index()`

Answer (score 2):

One option is with [awkward-pandas](https://awkward-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) which offers efficient handling of nested arrays/structs - depending on your data size, you may get significant performance over json_normalize :

```py
# pip install awkward-pandas
import pandas as pd
import awkward-pandas as akpd
df = result_df.astype({'IMSI_Operator':'awkward'})
df = df.set_index(['Date','Exception','Hour'])
out = df.unstack('Hour')
bsnl=out.apply(lambda f: f.ak['bsnl'].ak['unique_users'].mul([1,-1]).ak.sum())
other=out.apply(lambda f: f.ak['Other'].ak['unique_users'].mul([1,-1]).ak.sum())
(out
.drop(columns=('IMSI_Operator',2))
.droplevel(axis=1,level=1)
.assign(Hour=bsnl.index.get_level_values(1), 
        bsnl_unique_users_diff=bsnl.array, 
        other_unique_users_diff=other.array)
.reset_index()
.rename_axis(columns=None)
)

                  Date Exception                                      IMSI_Operator  Hour  bsnl_unique_users_diff  other_unique_users_diff
0  2023-09-06 00:00:00      s2ap  {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 60004, 'unique_use...     2                    1596                        5
1  2023-09-07 00:00:00      s2ap  {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 45224, 'unique_use...    13                   12291                       -5
```

This solution is tailored to the provided data; you may have to tweak the code to match your actual data. Plus, you should actually test the speed to be sure it is actually faster than json_normalize.

Another option is just to iterate through the dictionary, pull out the relevant values, groupby and reassign. You may suffer performance wise for relatively large data though, since the string accessor is within python space, so as always, test:

```py
out={'bsnl':result_df.IMSI_Operator.str['bsnl'].str['unique_users'], 
     'other': result_df.IMSI_Operator.str['Other'].str['unique_users']}

out = {key:value.groupby(result_df.Hour, sort=False).diff()
       for key, value in out.items()}

result_df.assign(**outt).dropna()

                  Date  Hour Exception                                      IMSI_Operator     bsnl  other
3  2023-09-07 00:00:00     2      s2ap  {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 47713, 'unique_use...  -1596.0   -5.0
2  2023-09-07 00:00:00    13      s2ap  {'bsnl': {'total_sessions': 45224, 'unique_use... -12291.0    5.0
```

Comment: Interesting alternative, but how efficient is the `ak` accessor? Is this just syntactic sugar over loops?

Comment: optimized in C++ land, quite efficient. the for loop is done in C++